# TVS diodes clamping voltage against waveform and current

Tags: voltage, diodes, tvs, diode-clamp

Having come across these two datasheets, two patterns might be inferred:

1. Clamping voltage increases with current: https://www.tme.eu/Document/edf5842caa2ca49fd1e87fde0a7b9438/sts32xxxxuxxx.pdf
2. Clamping voltage changes significantly with waveforms: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/662439/STMICROELECTRONICS/SM6T12AY.html

Is it safe to infer these two patterns for most of TVS diodes or are these two cases outliers and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STS32:

> Solid-state silicon-avalanche technology

ST doesn't actually say they're avalanche diodes, but there's very little else they could be.

A basic Thevenin diode model will suffice for this type; see Fig.3 from https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae37/slvae37.pdf:

[image]

That is, for applied voltage above breakdown, the diode acts as a voltage source plus resistance. The internal resistance is sometimes specified, or can be approximated from ratings. In general the resistance varies with current (this is a linearized approximation), but in general it will also tend to decrease (with rising current) towards an asymptotic minimum value, which can be understood as intrinsic internal resistances -- connecting leads and bulk silicon, those sorts of things.

You may find this and related documents informative:

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an1847-transient-protection-solutions-transil-diode-versus-varistor-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it safe to infer these two patterns for most of TVS diodes or are
> these two cases outliers and nothing else ?*

Definitely you can say this for all TVS devices: -

> *Clamping voltage increases with current*

And you can say this: -

> *Clamping voltage changes significantly with waveforms*

But, that 2nd statement is missing the point because, it is covered by the first statement. See this extract from the data sheet you linked: -

[image]

I've highlighted the 10/1000 μs waveform in red and, the 8/20 μs waveform in blue and, it's clear that the difference in clamping voltage is due to the difference in peak current being handled.

Comment: I'd say the same for any protection device, thinking of varistors and GDT

Comment: @LuC that's why I used the term "devices" in my opening sentence.

Comment: So, for example last row in the table above, if `I_max` of transient were 18A in both waveforms then only the `V_clamp = 33.2V` would apply ?

Comment: @kellogs pretty much I'd say.